# How to fast parse a list of JSON string?

Tags: r, rjson

I used `rjson` and do this `JSON <- lapply(data$toParse, fromJSON)`

my `toParse` has 600k rows of simple/short JSON.

However, it is very slow possibly because `fromJSON` doesn't vectorize operation so I have to use `lapply`.

I am wondering if there is any better way for parsing a list of JSON?

Comment: If nothing has changed for the last few months rjson is the only one json parser available for R. Alternative solution could be parsing json some external tools and preprocessing your data. There is pretty extensive list of available libraries on http://www.json.org/

Comment: @zero323 there is also RJSONIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about pasting the text into an array and parsing, `rjson::fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste(data$toParse, collapse=",")))`?

Comment: I had come up similar idea, but didn't think it would work out much improvement. However, the benchmark shows 30% faster

Comment: so in my case sprintf + paste is faster than lapply + Fun via Rprof